# Editing the woocommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and would like to add a custom text to the cart page.
So I add a product to cart, go to the cart and in there I see that the cart uses the page.php template.

My theme folder is called woocommerce, then inside my theme folder I created a folder called woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php

I added text to the new cart.php but it does not work.

How can I override the woocommerce cart page?

It is my first time using woocommerce so I really hope you can help

Thanks in advance

Comment: The correct path  in your theme folder is: woocommerce/cart/cart.php…  When starting, you copy the woocommerce **"templates"** subfolder into your theme folder. Then you just rename that copied folder to **"woocommerce"**…

Answer (score 0):

Create woocommerce/woocommerce/cart/cart.php , folder templates should not be there if you are using theme to override default woocommerce php's
See the article
**Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme**
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/